# Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference when invoking textview html code from string.xml file

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I am going to add HTML code in each time in the textview, for that I have written my paragraph in my `string.xml` file and taken that every thing to `story.java` file, then I added one `textview` to show that text.

I don't know if it will work or not. So,first of all Is this a correct logic? If correct then,  I am getting `Null pointer error`.

Please give solution to solve this.

This is my `Story.java` file.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class story extends AppCompatActivity {
Button next;
Button prev;
TextView t;
int count=0;
int[] stories = {
        R.string.firststory,
        R.string.story2,
        R.string.story3,
        R.string.story4,
        R.string.story5,
        R.string.story6,
        R.string.story7,
        R.string.story8,
        R.string.story9,
        R.string.story10,
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.story);

    next = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.next);
    prev = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.prev);
    t = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textview);
    t.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(stories[0])));
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            count=count+1;
            if(count<=10) {
                t.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(stories[count])));
            }
            else
            {
                Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"This is Last story",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        }
    });
    prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            count=count-1;
            if(count>=0)
            {
            t.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(stories[count])));
            }
            else{
                Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"This is first story",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

And this is my `story.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<Button
    android:text="previous"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/prev"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:text="next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add you error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `story.xml` file your `TextView` has id `textView2` but in the java code you are finding that view using id `textview`. Make sure you use the same id at both places.

```
t = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textview);
```

Comment: Thank You. If I am using two different text views in two different xml files, even though it is taking as textview1 in first file and textview2 in second file(i.e automatically created id|). That's why confused.

Answer (score 0):

You have given TextView id as **textView2** in xml but yoou are using **textview** in java file for TextView. Either update the id in xml as `textview` or give proper id in java file.